# Why do i get ERROR when I launch : flutter pub get flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

Tags: flutter

I don't know what to do here...please help. I just want to add app icon to it and I have no idea what I did wrong.[image]

[image]

Comment: First Try to run **flutter pub get** then run **flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main**

Comment: oh....I did that before but instead I wrote flutter pub run flutter... I typed flutter pub get run... anyways thanks man